# Sharing a chart

Tags: codenameone

I am using the Chart (line chart specifically) and ChartComponent classes to create some charts in my app, and I want to share them with a ShareButton.

I got everything to work by creating an image, getting its graphics context, and painting the container that the ChartComponent is placed in with the Image's graphics context EXCEPT the line on the chart doesn't show up.

The chart axes and labels are all there, just no lines. How can I create an image of the whole chart that I could share with the ShareButton?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was somewhat problematic on iOS. Charts relied on the new 2D shape API's which were unsupported on the mutable images used to draw upon.

This was fixed in recent updates: https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/1629

Comment: I recently added support for 2D transformation and shape APIs on mutable images. These should be on the build server so you should now be able to share your charts.